# Best Practices for multiple OS consistency when using Ruby's Dir.glob

Tags: ruby, canonicalization

I noticed recently during a debugging session that `Dir.glob` (aka `Dir[]`) behaves differently depending on the OS. Specifically the order the files are returned in is different.

What are recommended ways to use `Dir.glob` in Ruby when you know the code will be used on a variety of OSes?

Example Difference:
I cloned the project [DeckSchrubber](https://github.com/fraunhoferfokus/deckschrubber) in Linux and Windows

Windows:

```
irb(main):003:0> puts Dir['./*']
./CHANGELOG.md
./LICENSE
./main.go
./README.md
./types.go
./util
=> nil
```

Linux:

```
irb(main):011:0> puts Dir['./*']
./main.go
./LICENSE
./util
./types.go
./README.md
./CHANGELOG.md
=> nil
```

Once again I am asking for solutions and idioms to ensure the output is canonical.

Comment: Can you give an example of such differences? I know that Ruby's I/O and file libraries are deliberately *not* intended to be portable (matz has explicitly said so on multiple occasions), but I don't see anything in the documentation that seems to openly indicate an instance of such behavior for this particular method.

Comment: If you are worried about the order why not sort it? Regardless of the order they are returned in sorting will always be the same.

Comment: I agree with sorting? curious as to why that is not built in but I guess it was a YAGNI thing. If you need to sort it you can. I've never thought of a case where it shouldn't be sorted though...

Comment: Again, can you explain what *exactly* this difference is that you are seeing that you attribute to the OS? I don't see any differences in the results you posted. (The order is different, obviously, but the documentation of the method doesn't guarantee any ordering anyway, so the method is allowed to return any order it wants.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag one difference is the order. There may be other differences. I think one that is documented is .dotfiles behavior that is different. So yes there is one exact difference that I'm highlighting. That is the order. The question is now amended with an added sentence to call that out. Sure the method is allowed to return whatever it wants now I want to ensure standardization of format and am wondering where/if canonicalization has been formally approached or considered.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you determine that this difference is due to the OS and not, for example, the filesystem? Or the implementation? I know that, for example, on some implementations of Ruby, `Dir::[]` returns what the OS's `glob` function returns. The `glob` function, in turn, returns whatever the relevant syscall returns, which in turn returns what the relevant filesystem driver returns. At least on some filesystems, that will be in ascending order of inode numbers, and at least on some filesystem, inodes are allocated linearly. So, in that case, the order is completely …

Comment: … independent of the OS and only dependent on which order you created the files in. But nonetheless, there is no order guarantee in the documentation, so every order is equally valid, and every order is equal.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, FS libraries behave in a different way on Mac and Linux. I don't consider windows as a platform for Ruby.

So, from my experience, it was enough just to add a conditional operator, that checks the current platform name, and sorts the result in required way. As far as I remember, the difference was in the order of returned files.

Comment: I made the question clearer. Despite my preference for Linux and OSX I still work with Windows and Ruby. The experience is not bad.